# How to update the first N rows with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I want only update first N row, in SQL:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET c1 = 'XXX' WHERE Id IN (SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY c2)
```

Can Hibernate do that in *ONE* update?

Answer (score 1):

With Hibernate, you can always issue a native query as such, but the current running [Persistence Context won't be aware of the deleted entries](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

As long as you only deleted a relatively small amount of entries, you can simply select N entities and then use the remove operation so that you can benefit from optimistic locking checks and [prevent lost updates](https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/).

If you want to deletes lots of entries, then a bulk delete query is much more appropriate. You can even run the SQL DELETE query that you mentioned. That's exactly [the reason why JPA and Hibernate allow you to use native SQL queries anyway](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/).